# how to write sql query inside switch case in javascript?

Tags: javascript, mysql, dropdown

```
switch (depts.value) {          
  case 'General Physician':         
    var option = document.createElement('option');
    <?php 
       // I want to write mysql query so that it can fetch doctor name from db instead of write their name manually(what I have written bellow)  whoes department is general physician..and this doctor name will be shown in drop dowen box...I don't want to next 5 lines..
    ?>

    doctors.add(option);            
    break;
}
```

I want to write mysql query so that it can fetch doctor name from db instead of write their name manually(what I have written bellow)  whoes department is general physician..and this doctor name will be shown in drop dowen box...I don't want to next 5 lines..how this is possible???

Comment: please use small letters.

Comment: please if you know then advice me how can i do that? ...i am beginner .

Comment: Remove the second 'var' (before option). Read this [JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var) reference.

Comment: i removed it..now what i have to do??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't make a javascript function run PHP code because PHP runs on page load.

You must put the PHP code into a separate PHP file. Then you can make javascript run the PHP file using AJAX. The PHP file will then echo the doctor info back to the javascript.

Comment: Is there any way to do it without using jquery and using only javascript and php? Is there any framework for php to do the same?